# EmailTemplate is not accessible for community user in managed package

Tags: email, managed-package, salesforce1-app, email-template, security-scanner

I wanted to send an email using one of my Email Templates from community user. The email template folder where this email template is stored has Read/Write access & is accessible to all users.

```
if(EmailTemplate.SObjectType.getDescribe().isAccessible()){
    templateId = [Select id, HtmlValue from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName = 'XXXXX'];
}
```

the above soql is not execting and returning null value.

EmailTemplate is not accessible for community user in the managed package

Is anybody able to help me to what else I'm missing here?